# else if in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate a string based on user input and show some message:

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
    if(this.value.length<=158)
     $('#charCount').text('We will deduct 1 credit from your account');
    else if(this.value.length>158 || this.value.length<316)
         $('#charCount').text('We will deduct 2 credit from your account');
    else if(this.value.length>316 || this.value.length<400)
        $('#charCount').text('We will deduct 3 credit from your account');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p9jVB/11/

The problem is the last `else if` is not working... Have I missed something?

Comment: Other problem is that if you have a text which length's 316 it won't enter in any `if` statement.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you mean &&, not ||

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
    if(this.value.length<=158)
         $('#charCount').text('We will deduct 1 credit from your account');
    else if(this.value.length>158 && this.value.length<=316)
         $('#charCount').text('We will deduct 2 credit from your account');
    else if(this.value.length>316 && this.value.length<400)
        $('#charCount').text('We will deduct 3 credit from your account');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> else if(this.value.length>158 || this.value.length<316)
>     $('#charCount').text('We will deduct 2 credit from your account');
> else if(this.value.length>316 || this.value.length<400)
>     $('#charCount').text('We will deduct 3 credit from your account');
> ```

Every number in the world is greater than 158 *or* less than 316, so the alternative condition will never be reached.